# How to change the orange theme to something else?

Tags: themes

With Ubuntu, you have the orange like theme that shows when you highlight something or click on something. That colour orange is very tacky. How can I change that colour to a colour like blue or make that colour translucent or even transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pretty much download a lot of themes from the Internet, but you can also install Cinnamon. Cinnamon is a fork of GNOME Shell used for Linux Mint. It is fully configurable. However, it is quite complicated to install at first, and it will replace Unity, so if you just wanted to change the basic theme, this may not be for you.

To proceed, open the terminal, and type in the following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Dash, open System Settings or do a search for Appearance and open it. From there, you can change the overall system theme. If you want even finer control over your theme, install `gnome-tweak-tool`

Comment: How do I install it via the terminal.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool` It will show up in Dash as "Advanced Settings" and add a few new themes to choose from. You can install GTK-3 themes available from sources around the Internet.